# Angular7 multiple child routes with empty path

Tags: angular, routes

**Hi StackOverflow**

I am new to Angular, and currently developing an application for learning purposes.

I have one root module (app), and two child modules (quiz and question).

**Expected behavior**

- If I surf to / => I want to show the QuestionListComponent in the QuestionModule
- If I surf to /question => I want to show the QuestionListComponent in the QuestionModule
- If I surf to /quiz => I want to show the QuizComponent in the QuizModule

**Current behavior**

- If I surf to / => QuestionListComponent is loaded
- If I surf to /question => QuestionListComponent is loaded
- If I surf to /quiz => QuestionListComponent is loaded instead of QuizComponent

**AppModule routes**

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'questions' },
  { path: 'quiz', loadChildren: './quiz/quiz.module#QuizModule' },
  { path: 'questions', loadChildren: './question/question.module#QuestionModule'}
]);
```

**QuestionModule routes**

```
RouterModule.forChild([
      { path: '', component: QuestionListComponent },
      { path: 'new', component: QuestionFormComponent, canDeactivate: [UnsavedChangesGuard] },
      { path: 'edit/:id', component: QuestionFormComponent, canDeactivate: [UnsavedChangesGuard] },
    ]),
```

**QuizModule routes**

```
RouterModule.forChild([
      { path: '', component: QuizComponent }
    ])
```

**Question**

Obviously, the problem is that when surfing to /quiz, angular finds the '' path in the QuestionModule first and loads the corresponding content.

But, how would I fix this, so that when surfing to /quiz, the QuizComponent is loaded?

**Router tree**
For some reason, the Question components falls under the quiz node

[image: Router tree for my problem]

Comment: Try putting the ```''``` empty redirectTo path in your forRoot routes as the *last* path, after questions. The Angular router is picky about the order of routes. You can also enable tracing of the router for debugging purposes: https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It doesn't work. The forRoot empty path is also not the problem. I enabled tracing of the router. It renders these routes and picks the empty one from the QuestionModule:






routes: Array(4)
0: {path: "new", canDeactivate: Array(1), component: ƒ}
1: {path: "edit/:id", canDeactivate: Array(1), component: ƒ}
2: {path: "", component: QuestionModule} <= this one is picked
3: {path: "", component: QuizModule}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue.

I included the QuestionModule in the QuizModule, causing Angular to merge the forChild routes. I removed it.

Now my router tree is looking good.

[image: Correct router tree]